# how to call an activity which extends the baseactivity

Tags: android, subactivity

i am writing one activity class like below

```
public class HeaderFooter extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.headerfooter);
        }
 }
```

and i am extending one more class from HeaderFooter class

```
public class Home extends HeaderFooter 
{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
            ViewGroup.inflate(Home.this, R.layout.home, vg);
        }
}
```

how to call the extended class from base class on listitemclick event

if i try with the following code

```
  Intent i=new Intent(HeaderFooter .this, Home .class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

i am getting the exception tell me how to call extended class from my main class.

Exception details:

```
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pcmac.parentconnect/com.pcmac.parentconnect.Grades}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.pcmac.parentconnect.LayerStack.onCreate(LayerStack.java:174)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at com.pcmac.parentconnect.Grades.onCreate(Grades.java:15)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-21 07:17:44.173: E/AndroidRuntime(1522):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What exception you got??

Comment: i will post the logcat is it a way to call an activity

Comment: Whats that exception?

Comment: The way you have written seems to be right.
What exception you got?
Have you mentioned your activity in the manifest file?

Comment: Better call the Function/ methode u want rather than calling class. Home temp = new Home(); temp.requiredmethode();

Comment: what u r doing tell exactly what u need ?

Comment: Why are you inflating R.layout.home? Are you inflating headerfooter for HeaderFooter class as the decor view and for Home do you want to use home layout instead?

Comment: i am implementing slideout menu i want to run different activity on each listitem click so i make one linearlayout and swithing the activities in the same view

Comment: ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata); in which layout file it is residing.R.id.lldata is in which file

Comment: in headerfooter layout file i created a layout file

Comment: com.pcmac.parentconnect.Grades.onCreate(Grades.java:15).
What is Grades?

Comment: java class which is extending  HeaderFooter  java class

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to use the other constructor of Intent:

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setClassName(context, getTargetActivityClassName() /* child class override this method and return a string */);
```